# ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool when trying to sort a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dataframe, sorting, pyspark

I am having a list created in a bit complex way inside a loop
like this

```
myList.append(abs(lit(row.uniqonline - (row.p * row.adj_v1))) / np.amin([row.uniqonline, (row.p * row.adj_v1)]))
```

This is all good. But when I tried using a numpy percentile function I got an error, which is related to the sort function, which the percentile-built-in function uses.

Trying just to use a simple sort function on this list I got this error:

```
"ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
"
```

What should i do?

Comment: Please show the whole code and some data so we can help you.

Comment: But it's too complex.  And it would  be confusing.  I thought  better show this snippet.  I think its easier and I think the problem  should  be here. And related to differences of python  2 vs python  3. As this code worked well on python  2

Comment: You could check type of what is inside the array by `print(type(myList[0]))` - if it's something other than float then the problem could lie in that, or maybe somewhere you are dividing by 0.